# Pending edits on posts, to be made when the site is lower in traffic

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

[We are burninating](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58557440#58557440) the [hessian](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hessian) tag, and I finished half of this job by removing the tag from all of the unanswered questions. I'm hesitant to remove the tag from the other two which already have answers, since bumping those questions up to the top right now seems a bad idea when we've had an influx of a lot of unanswered questions lately.

When we reach another low-traffic day, we can remove the tag from the following two questions (which would complete the burnination process):

- [GAMESS(US) Hessian calculation sometimes does not produce the IR intensities](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/4291/5)
- [Why is CPHF/CPKS necessary for calculating second derivatives?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/3787/5)
- [Can the dehydrogenation energy be negative?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/6417/5)

---

- Switch from [organic-chemistry](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organic-chemistry) to [organic-matter](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organic-matter).
- Burninate one of [microstructure](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microstructure) or [micro-structure-evolution](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/micro-structure-evolution).
- Burninate [thermo-electric](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thermo-electric) if the tag is still not relevant later on, and at the same time we can change "0 D" to "0-dimensional" here: [How to calculate Transport coeffiecients for 0 D systems?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/4120/5)
- methodology tag.

Comment: Why? I don't get it.

Comment: @Camps Are you wondering why the tag is being burninated, or why the tag is being burninated so gradually?

Comment: Nike: why is being burninated.

Comment: @Camps [we had some discussion about it here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58557279#58557279) Tyberius and I gave some reasons for it. Is there a reason you want to keep that tag? In 15 months it was only used on 4 questions and one of them was already closed. I guess we could have a broader discussion about whether or not we want to keep "small tags". We're a small site (almost 3000 users) and already have more tags than site like Blender which have 105,000+ users, but this alone doesn't mean we have to remove small tags.

Comment: I saw the discussion there. But I am really not seeing a real practical necessity  to burn it. For me, because only 4 questions (even closed ones) use the tag does not cause any problem to the site, to the community at all.

Comment: @Camps Good point. We can have a broader discussion about what to do with "small tags". I can also do research about why other sites across the network seem not to be a fan of having tags like that. I guess the "harm" is that we have more tags to "maintain", but you're right that this is not so harmful in comparison to other things.

Comment: Just a question: a first time user can define its own tags? I don't remember if our site block this as other sites do.

Comment: @Camps a user needs to have 150 points on MMSE to create their own tags.

Comment: So, this is a major justification to keep this tag :)

Comment: @Camps There was some prior discussion way back during beta about why having a moderate number of tags that cover a lot of questions could be better than having lots of tags that may only cover 1-2 questions. https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/tagging-it-really-is-important-and-we-need-to-focus-more-on-it

Answer (score 2):

I felt the last few days were slow enough, so I edited the tags on these questions. There are currently no other questions with [hessian](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hessian). While nothing prevents this tag from being re-added, I have yet to see a question that would need this tag and I can't think of a hypothetical question where it would be better than a more specific tag about the topic of the question.